# Can a circuit traverse an edge twice?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find out if a *circuit* in a graph that uses the edge $ab$ may traverse the edge $ab$ more than once.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not traverse an edge twice (or more than twice) in a circuit.

The Circuit is nothing but a closed walk with no repeating edge and no repeating vertices(expect starting and terminating vertices).

For more info you can refer following link.
[What is difference between cycle, path and circuit in Graph Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655589/what-is-difference-between-cycle-path-and-circuit-in-graph-theory)

Comment: most definitions of "circuit" that I've seen allow for repeated vertices, but not repeated edges -- typically it's called a "cycle" if repeated vertices are not allowed (as in fact the accepted answer to the linked question states)